# How do I keybind SublimeREPL to run Haskell interpeter?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I've been searching for the right command name to keybind to run Haskell Interpeter in Sublime 3. I'm trying to add to the Sublime key bindings - user and the code should look something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad2"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_haskell_run",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }
},
```

The following line is wrong, I made it up and I need to find the right command to put there:

```
"id": "repl_haskell_run",
"file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Load the current file into the SublimeREPL GHCi or just open up a new SublimeREPL GHCi?

Comment: Open a new SublimeREPL GHCi, same as doing ctrl+shift+p -> SublimeREPL: Haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following does what you are looking for. I found the command by looking for a `.sublime-menu` file in the Haskell folder of the SublimeREPL repo: [`config/Haskell/Default.sublime-commands`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Haskell/Default.sublime-commands). (One such file had to exist for you to be able to do `ctrl + shift + p -> SublimeREPL: Haskell`.)

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+keypad2"],
      "command": "run_existing_window_command",
      "args": { "id": "repl_haskell", "file": "config/Haskell/Main.sublime-menu" } },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.